# Añadir un texto cuando hago click

Tags: flutter, dart, botón

soy nueva en flutter.
Quería saber cómo puedo hacer para que cuándo hago click en un botón me muestre debajo un texto, y si vuelvo a pulsar el botón me muestre debajo del anterior texto, el mismo texto y asi las veces que el usuario pulse el botón.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería con un `StatefullWidget` donde una `List` almacene los textos que quieres ir agregando y estos vayan siendo mostrados, de la siguiente forma:

```
class RespStackoverflow extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<RespStackoverflow> createState() => _RespStackoverflowState();
}

class _RespStackoverflowState extends State<RespStackoverflow> {
  List<Widget> listaDeTextos = [];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children:[
        MaterialButton( //Este será el botóon que el usuario debe presionar
          onPressed: () { 
            setState(() { //Debes llamar al setState para que el widget se redibuje con los nuevos elementos de la lista listaDeTextos
              listaDeTextos.add(const Text("Texto que se muestra debajo"));
            });
           },
          child: const Text("Agregar texto"),
        ),
        ...listaDeTextos //spredOperator con los elementos del la lista
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

En este caso utilizo un `Column` para no aumentar la complejidad del problema, pero en un futuro cuando ya tengas más conocimientos de Flutter será mejor que los textos los generes con un [ListView.builder](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists)

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funcionó perfectamente!!

Comment: Y si quisiera en vez de un texto, que me cargara un componente que tengo creado en otro fichero?

Comment: en vez de agregar Text en el listaDeTextos.add() puedes agregar el componente que quieras